# How to assign values from a list to a dictionary and back into a separate list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am trying to make a loop that can roll my dice and assign the rolled value into a list that can then be put through a dictionary to get back the values written in the dictionary.
My dictionary is as follows:

```
scores = {1:1000, 2:200, 3:300, 4:400, 5:500, 6:600}
rolls = []
for i in range(5):
    self.rolls.append(random.randint(1,6))
my_score = 0
```

How do I make the values in rolls that of the ones in the dictionary and add them to `my_score`.

Comment: `my_score += sum(scores[a] for a in rolls)` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

scores = {'1':1000, '2':200, '3':300, '4':400, '5':500, '6':600}
results  = 0
rolls = []
for i in range(5):
    rand_int = random.randint(1,6)
    if rand_int == 1:
        results += (scores['1'])
    elif rand_int == 2:
        results +=(scores['2'])
    elif rand_int == 3:
        results += (scores['3'])
    elif rand_int == 4:
        results +=(scores['4'])
    elif rand_int == 5:
        results += (scores['5'])
    elif rand_int == 6:
        results += (scores['6'])
```

print(results)

change the dictionary key to string